# Docker build is failing

Tags: docker, apache-spark, spark-ui

I am trying to upload ca-certificate stored in my windows location to docker container but while running the build image it is failing.

I am not getting how to copy the certificate from windows location to linux recommended location.

```
FROM amazonlinux:2
FROM amazoncorretto:8
FROM maven:3.6-amazoncorretto-8

RUN yum install -y procps
WORKDIR /tmp/
ADD pom.xml /tmp
RUN cp ~/Users/<username>/<bundle>.pem  /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
RUN update-ca-trust
#RUN curl -O   ./spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz  https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
RUN curl    -O  ./spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz  -I https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
RUN tar -xzf spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz && \
    mv spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop /opt/spark && \
    rm spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
RUN mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=/opt/spark/jars/
RUN rm /opt/spark/jars/jsr305-3.0.0.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/jersey-*-1.19.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/jackson-dataformat-cbor-2.6.7.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/joda-time-2.8.1.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/jmespath-java-*.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-core-*.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-kms-*.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/aws-java-sdk-s3-*.jar && \
    rm /opt/spark/jars/ion-java-1.0.2.jar

RUN echo $'\n\
spark.eventLog.enabled                      true\n\
spark.history.ui.port                       18080\n\
' > /opt/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]:


cp: cannot stat ‘/root/Users/<username>/<bundle>.pem’: No such file or directory
```

Without this when I am trying to run using , it gives warning  0curl: (6) Could not resolve host:

and then could not run next command because of error
spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory

```
RUN curl    -O --insecure  ./spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz  -I https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-3.1.1/spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz

RUN tar -xzf spark-3.1.1-bin-without-hadoop.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

If your pem file is outside of Docker and you are trying to copy it into Docker,
You need to put the pem file besides your Dockerfile and use `ADD` or `COPY` [instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/):

```
COPY bundle.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
```

and always its better to not to use relative path `~` in Dockerfiles.